# REstart activity from Service

Tags: android

I can start activity from service but I cannot restart it, this flag only brings to front the existing activity:

```
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

how could I restart (finish the old, start new)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bit a trickery but what you can do is to add something like `RESTART=true` to the intent that calls the Activity. In activity's `onResume` you can do `getIntent` and see if that flag exists and if so call `finish()` and call activity anew

Comment: thx, but onResume is not called, when Activity is in foreground

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that your activity is still on the screen. If that's the case then receiver is good way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Try finishing the activity first by calling:

```
activity.finish();
```

then do a new intent to start the activity again:

```
myIntent = new Intent(context, activity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```